# Cal like calendar implementation

Tags: android, calendar, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I'm trying to implement Cal app like calendar in my application.

I'm making use of [synchronized scrolling technique](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/07/18/android-tips-and-tricks-synchronized-scrolling.html).

I want to know which is a better calendar library as there are quite a few.  have short listed [android-time-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) and [caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid).

Can anyone suggest which is better to work with when it is necessary to be used simply as a view in a fragment or activity for easy synchronized scrolling?

Any other tips regarding the cal like calendar implementation are also welcome.

Thank you.